# problems when submitting to Storm on HDinsight in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, submit, apache-storm

I am trying to submit a C# storm topology from Visual Studio 2013 to a storm cluster in Windows Azure. After I right click the project from VS and select "submit to Storm on HDinsight", I got a popup window asking for the storm cluster name. I choose the storm cluster name from the drop down list and click submit. Then I saw the project is built successfully. But after that, nothing happens from the Topology Submission Output window.

I tried with another C# storm topology. And I can see that after I click submit, the Topology Submission Output window shows that the .spec file is being generated, .zip file is being generated, etc and it is submitted.

How to debug this issue? Where to look what command/scripts are run after the submit button is clicked?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I installed VS2013 with update 5 and it seems the problem is resolved.